# Angular animation on every click

Tags: angular, animation

How to run animation in Angular on every button click?
It runs only once on state change, when I change state back on timeout an click again nothing happens.

```
export const flashAnimation = trigger('Flash', [
  transition('no => yes', [ animate('500ms ease-in-out', keyframes([
    style({ background: '#fff' }), style({ background: 'none' }) ])) ]),
]);

...

@HostBinding('@Flash')
public Flash: string = 'no';

...

public onClick() {
  this.Flash = 'yes';
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.Flash = 'no';
  }, 1000);
}
```

Angular version 10.0.3

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? It works for me with Angular 9

Comment: Angular version 10.0.3